# Typing in dropdown selection with spaces

Tags: google-chrome

I often interact with very long dropdowns (i.e. comboboxes) that contain a large number of entries. Often these entries have spaces. When I try to type in an entry with spaces, the dropdown opens as soon as I hit the spacebar. Previously, it would simply skip to the selection as if I'd typed it. I'm not sure if this is due to a change in chrome or in some other plugins I have.

Is there a standard way of typing out a dropdown entry when it has spaces?

Comment: This would seem to be a problem with the creator / vendor of the website itself.

Comment: @mdpc This happens with multiple websites.

Comment: Same problem here. here's a [related bug report (Chrome Help Forum)](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/IxVN2zuOlXc), which has also gone unanswered.